# Is there an order for compilation?

Tags: c, gcc

For compile C programm

```
gcc -ansi - Wall  
gcc -Wall -ansi
```

Is it the same action ?

And it must be **-ansi** or i can write **-Ansi** ?

Thanks

Comment: "*`- Wall`*" is not the same as "*`-Wall`*".

Comment: Writting mistake

Comment: IXish systems are often picky about cases. So use the options as specified by the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: I would suggest a newer C standard than ansi which is 20 years obsolete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The order is not important when you compile with flags and try with a capital letter to see if it does the same thing:)

Comment: The functionality of certain linker options which may be passed to GCC very well depends on where those option occur on the command line. Typically the `-l` (ell) option is critical.

Comment: Just 'trying' to see if it works  is a blueprint to writing non standard conforming and hence unportable code. *NEVER DO THIS* ! Look at the documentation of the Compiler for Christ s sake!

Comment: `-std=c99 -std=c11` is different to `-std=c11 -std=c99'